# Metadata information in Oracle NoSql

Tags: metadata, oracle-nosql

I want to view the schema of data which are being stored in kvstore , like what are the keys and their type and also values and their type(as Oracle NoSql is a key-value store). As per my knowledge we can use "show schema " command but it will work only if Avro schema is added in that particular store and second thing is it will give the information of only value names and its type but key name and its type is still a bottleneck.
So is there any utility I can use to view the structure of data like we use "describe" command in oracle SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that 'kv->show schema' will show you the field names (columns) and its types when you have a Avro schema. When you don't register a schema then database have no knowledge of what your value object looks like. In that case client application maintains the schema of the value field (instead of the database).

About the keys, a) keys are always string type b) you can view them from the datashell prompt if you do something like this "kv-> get kv -keyonly -all".

I would also like to mention that in the upcoming R3 release we will be introducing table data model which will give you much closer experience to relational database (in case of table definitions). You can take a look of a webinar we did on this subject: http://bit.ly/1lPazSZ.

Hope that helps,
Anuj